# I got this error while running simple Hibernate application "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and try this simple code in eclipse indigo and hibernate 4.3.10. I am using jre7.

I got this error log in consol

```
 Jul 22, 2015 10:05:22 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Jul 22, 2015 10:05:22 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:295)
    at com.milind.hibernate.HibernateTest.createSessionFactory(HibernateTest.java:16)
    at com.milind.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:221)
    ... 5 more
```

I try lot to resolve this error please help me with this.
I am newbie to hibernate.

HibernateTest.java

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import com.milind.hibernate.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Milind");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}

}
```

UserDetails.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
private int userId;
private String userName;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property  name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3535/students</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>        
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>  

<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>            
 <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>       

<!-- Mapping files -->
<mapping class="com.milind.hibernate.dto.UserDetails"/>
```

Comment: Looks like your chibernate.cfg.xml is not found in classpath.

Comment: Actully it is in src folder.

Comment: Is the src folder in your classpath?

Comment: ya source folder is in class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**: hibernate configuration file **hibernate.cfg.xml**  is not available at class path.

> **solution:** Add your hibernate.cfg.xml file to class path.

In case your hibernate configuration file is not named as "hibernate.cfg.xml" then you need to specify the name of the configuration file as well.

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
cfg.configure("filePath/your-config-file-name.cfg.xml");
```

Comment: How can i add this file to class path?

if it is done by putting in source folder then it is already in source folder.

Comment: make sure your configuration file name  must be 'hibernate.cfg.xml'. It you want to keep it in source folder. I should be directly inside the **src**.

Comment: name is same as you suggest and it is directly inside src folder. Actually one of my friend suggest me this solution so i try this solution but still getting error.